# Change a date reference as text to Google Sheets date format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Need to change "December 23, 2019 at 08:31PM"
to a date Google Sheets recognize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula for eg. cell `J16`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(J16,"at ","")
```

Then copy and paste on top `Values only`. Then change the format.

---

`December 23, 2019 08:31PM` is what you need.

Please make sure you don't have the cell formatted as text. You can have it either at `Automatic` or as `Number`> `Date time`.
Read more about [custom date and time formats](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470)

Comment: Yes, that is what I need. But changing format won't work. I am exporting the data from IFTTT so I get the date as text.... but can not change it to date format using default formatting option. Thks in advance

Comment: You don't just change the format. You need to delete `at ` as well.

Comment: to 100 cells? I know I could do it manually, but I am trying to find a way, maybe a formula to do it automaticly. Thanks

Comment: Please check the edited answer.